# Pasar parametro en JasperPHP y Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo el siguiente codigo en PHP bajo Laravel
necesito pasar el id de la factura y el nombre de la cuenta. pero no funciona. solo me permite enviar un solo parametro en el array. si quito el $cuenta->nombre, me funciona perfecto.

Error generado con 2 parametro
Exception in JasperPHP.php line 187:
Your report has an error and couldn't be processed! Try to output the command using the function `output();` and run it manually in the console.

```
public function compilarFacturaOficina($grupo, $cabezera , $archivo ){
    $ruta = '/public/comprobantes/facturas/';        
    $archivoCompilado = 'Blank_A4';
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $cuenta = Cuenta::find($cabezera->cuenta_id);

    switch ($grupo) {
        case 9927:
            // Crear el objeto JasperPHP
            $jasper = new JasperPHP;
            //dd($factura_id);

            $jasper->process(
            base_path($ruta . $archivoCompilado),
            false,
            array('pdf', 'rtf', 'html' ,'xls'),
            array('factura_id' => $cabezera->id , 'cuenta' => $cuenta->nombre)
            )->execute();
            break;

        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }


}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado lo que te dice de la función output? ¿Qué valor tiene $cuenta->nombre? Por si tiene caracteres extraños que puedan no gustarle

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que quizás deberías pasar los valores del array igual (te falta el nombre del elemento 'cuenta' y la flecha):

```
array('factura_id' => $cabezera->id , 'cuenta' => $cuenta->nombre)
```

Comment: Lo tengo asi pero no me funciona.

Comment: Según el código que has puesto no está así. Si lo tienes así, edita el post y ponlo como lo tengas para evitar confusión

Comment: Listo corregido el post. gracias